# Python remove whitespace beautiful soup and strip

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html email that I've extracted the text from using beautiful soup, then I'd like to remove any leading whitespace, but no matter how many times I try textwrap.dedent or string.strip() it doesn't remove the whitespace from certain lines. I've done a print repr(string) and the output is this.

```
\r\n   content
```

Meaning there is actual whitespace between the \r and the content on the lines that continue to have whitespace even when I use strip or anything else to remove them. How do I handle this?

Code right now:

```
no_html = BeautifulSoup(message).get_text()
final_message = no_html.strip()
print final_message
```

Comment: Try `no_html.rstrip().strip()`

Comment: No luck, same result

Comment: Are you sure it's `\n\r`?  `\r\n` is a valid line separator in windows, but `\n\r` is not (and is not anywhere else that I'm familiar with), and so will not be parsed as whitespace.

Comment: You're right it's actually \r\n, but I think I've figured out a solution. Will post below

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
no_html.rstrip().strip()
```

Removed all '/t/n' separators from my code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like split() works for me in this instance.

adding the following code:

```
newmsg = newmsg + "\n" + ' '.join(line.split())
```